# Determining the lowest rank non-vanishing multipole moment

Tags: symmetry, group-theory

I have been told that the multipole moments of rank 0,1,2,3,...n have respectively 1,3,5,7,...2n+1 components which transform like the spherical harmonics of rank 0,1,2,3,...n. How do I use the character tables to determine the lowest rank non-vanishing multipole moment for the following molecules: $\ce{H2O, BF3, CF4, CO2, SF6}$?