# Polarity of the phosphate ion?

Tags: bond, polarity

I understand that phosphate is bonded covalently, however, it is characterized as a polyatomic ion. This is making me confused on whether it's polar or non-polar.

Comment: Hi and welcome to chemistry.stackexchange.com. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. Visit the [help] to learn more about it.

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/8667/determining-the-lowest-rank-non-vanishing-multipole-moment

Answer (score 6):

There are multiple different things to consider for phosphate $\ce{PO4^3-}$:

- The bonds themselves. Each of the four $\ce{P-O}$ single bonds is polarised towards the oxygen. Each bond is *polar.*
- The molecule as a whole. It is of near-perfect tetrahedral shape thus having the point group $T_\mathrm{d}$. This point group includes the inversion symmetry operation $i$. Therefore, macroscopic properties of a vectorial type (like the overall dipole moment which is a vector more or less pointing from one pole to the other) must, by definition, be $0$. Thus, the entire molecule is *not a dipole.*
- The molecule’s total charge. It has an overall charge of $-3$. This charge is located on the surrounding oxygens but the entire thing can be simplified from far away to a ball with the charge in the centre, i.e. the phosphorus atom. We would consider this molecular ion a *monopole.*

Comment: Located entirely in centre? Really?

Comment: Symmetry, my dear @Mith; symmetry.

Comment: It' symmetrically on oxygens, however not exactly 3 - there's partial charge on P but definitely not such high.

Comment: @Mith I reworded. Better?

Comment: It's not monopole - if sth hasn't dipole moment it still can quadrupole moment

Comment: @Mithoron I admit defeat when it comes to any $n$-pole with $n > 2$. Mind noting that in an answer of your’s so I can learn? ;)

Answer (score 0):

A poly-atomic ion is a group of atoms that act as a single ion, it has no bearing on the bonding with-in the molecule.  The oxygen-phosphorous bonds are covalent but polar, the molecule its-self is charged, but lacks a direction across the molecule of the charge making phosphate non-polar.  The molecule its-self is free to bond covalent or ionicly depending on what it reacts with.